# Can't install php-devel on Centos 7

Tags: centos, yum

```
Error: Package: php-devel-7.4.2-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php74)
           Requires: php-cli(x86-64) = 7.4.2-1.el7.remi
           Installed: php-cli-7.4.3~RC1-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-modular-test)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 7.4.3~RC1-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-cli-5.4.16-46.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.16-46.el7
           Available: php-cli-5.4.16-46.1.el7_7.x86_64 (updates)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.16-46.1.el7_7
           Available: php-cli-5.4.45-17.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.45-17.el7.remi
           Available: php-cli-5.4.45-18.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.45-18.el7.remi
           Available: php-cli-5.5.38-11.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.5.38-11.el7.remi
           Available: php-cli-5.5.38-12.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.5.38-12.el7.remi
           Available: php-cli-5.6.40-16.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.6.40-16.el7.remi
           Available: php-cli-5.6.40-17.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.6.40-17.el7.remi
           Available: php-cli-7.4.1-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php74)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 7.4.1-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-cli-7.4.2-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php74)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 7.4.2-1.el7.remi
```

I need to deploy my website on a centos machine. For some reason, version php of 7.4 is installed here by the customer.
I already have php-cli working, but the package manager still can't install php-devel package. 
When i run `php-cli-7.4.1-1.el7.remi.x86_64`, it says that the package is already installed.
When i try to uninstall the package which is currently installed, it asks me if i want to remove all the php packages.
So what do i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your repository configuration is a mess, too much repositories enabled

- **remi-modular-test** is a testing repository and only for "dnf" users
- **remi-php*** each provides a different php version, you need to keep only one

So

```
yum-config-manager --disable remi-modular-test
yum-config-manager --disable remi-php55
yum-config-manager --disable remi-php56
```

As you have php-7.4.3RC1 installed you need the same version of php-devel

I recommend to switch to the stable version (7.4.2 for now)

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php74
yum downgrade php\*
yum install php-devel
```

Please for a proper configuration, follow the [wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) instructions

BTW, **php-devel** is mostly needed when you want to build a C extension, and as [most extensions](https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/PECL-extensions-RPM-status) are also packaged, you should use the package instead of building it from sources.